# New to perl - Dynamically entering a value for an array (a column) from a csv using perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I am new to perl and I need to write a perl script with the following requirements:

1. Need to read a csv file
2. Store the columns in a array
3. Suppose there are 7 fields (columns) in the csv: field 1, field 2, field 3,field 4,field 5,field 6,field 7

I need to be able to give any fields as input parameter dynamically. Suppose if I give input parameters as field 3, field 7 and the data in the csv is:

```
No of orders'|Date'|Year'|Exp_date'|Month'|time'|Committed
12'|12122002'|2013'|02022012'|12'|1230'|Yes
```

Then I want the output to be:

```
Year~Committed                          
2013~Yes
```

and the remaining columns also to be in the same format:

```
No of orders~Date~Exp_date~Month~time
12~12122002~02022012~12~1230
```

Currently I got a perl script from net which provides me the left sided result only in hardcoded format. But I want to give the input in run time and want the result to be generated.Help is appreciated.

```
$filename = 'xyz.csv';

# use the perl open function to open the file
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";

# loop through each line in the file
# with the typical "perl file while" loop
while(<FILE>)
{

  chomp;

  # read the fields in the current line into an array
  @fields = split('\`\|', $_);

 # print the concat
 print "$fields[0]~$fields[1]\n";
}


close FILE;
```

Comment: Do NOT try to parse CSV with regular expressions. Use `Text::CSV` instead.

Comment: But can I give columns as input parameters even if i use Text::csv?

Comment: `Text::CSV` parses the CSV file row by row, giving you an array of fields.  In this script, it would take the place of your `split()` command above.  How you manipulate the fields after that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to argue whether to use Text::CSV or not.  It is not relevant to the question and `split` is perfectly acceptable.

Here is how I would solve the problem, assuming that the poster wants to have input files of more than one line of data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# take any file name from the command line, instead of hard coding it
my ($filename) = @ARGV;
my @title;
my @table;

open FILE, "<", $filename or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";
while (<FILE>) {
  chomp;
  if (!@title) {
    @title = split '\'\|';
    next;
  }
  my @row = split '\'\|';
  # build an array of array references, a two dimensional table
  push @table, \@row;
}
close FILE;

print "Access which row? ";
my $row = <STDIN> - 1;
die "Row value is out of range for $filename\n" if (($row < 0) || ($row >= scalar(@table)));

print "Access which column? ";
my $col = <STDIN> - 1;
die "Column value is out of range for $filename\n" if (($col < 0) || ($col >= scalar(@title)));

print "$title[$col]\~$table[$row][$col]\n";
```

The first pass of the while loop will store the split values in our Title array.  The remaining passes will append our data, row by row, as array references to Table.  Then with some user prompting and basic error checking, we print our results.